# ¿Cómo habilitar login a un usuario en linux?

Tags: linux, login

Al tratar de hacer `#sudo su usuariox` aparece el siguiente error

```
Cannot execute /sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el comando que intentas ejecutar, y que distro de linux usas?

Comment: El shell se indica, por lo general, en el archivo `/etc/passwd`. Y la ruta de `nologin` tal vez sea dependiente de la distribución. En Ubuntu está en `/usr/sbin/nologin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que está ocurriendo es que el usuario tiene asignado como shell el comando `/sbin/nologin`, que además aparentemente no existe. Si el usuario va a tener una sesión interactiva, esto es acceso a un shell, podrías hacer algunas cosas:

#### 1. Editar directamente el archivo /etc/passwd

Normalmente para el usuario deberías tener una línea como la siguiente: `usuario:x:0:0:usuario:/home/usuario:/sbin/nologin` edita el último campo `/sbin/nologin`e indica el shell que normalmente usa el resto de los usuarios

#### 2. Usar el comando que indicaste en tu respuesta

`chsh -s {shell-name} {user-name}`

Ambos procedimientos hay que efectuarlos como `root`